# How to implement bass effect in android?

Tags: android, media-player, bass

I want to develop a bass effect for media player.Can any body help me regarding this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to isolate the low-frequency components. You will need an FFT to do this... there's one linked to [this older S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774104/android-audio-fft-to-retrieve-specific-frequency-magnitude-using-audiorecord).

After you've got the frequency representation of your audio data, alter the magnitudes of the low-frequency components as you see it, run the inverse transform to convert it back to audio samples, and pass it to the audio hardware for playback.

Comment: thanks for reply, how to pass audio samples to audio hardware,can you explain me ?

Comment: The Java API on Android is AudioTrack. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html