# Audio analysis on Android phone

Tags: android, audio, fft

I want to develop an android app that takes in the audio signal and generates the time and frequency domain values.

I have the audio in a buffer which is obtained from the android MIC. I want to use this buffer values to generate a frequency domain graph. Is there some code that would help me find the FFT of an audio signal??

I have seen Moonblink's Audalyzer code and there are some missing components in the code. I could find lots of missing modules. I want to find a better logic that would take in audio and perform some calculations on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found these for you using duckduckgo:

- [Android audio FFT to retrieve specific frequency magnitude using audiorecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774104/android-audio-fft-to-retrieve-specific-frequency-magnitude-using-audiorecord)
- http://www.digiphd.com/android-java-reconstruction-fast-fourier-transform-real-signal-libgdx-fft/

This should help