# Real time audio frequency detection form mic

Tags: android

I need to determine in real time the frequency of sound coming from the mic. I know a FFT has to be applied to the incoming audio data, but I was wondering if anyone is aware of a library or some sample code that shows how to get real-time audio frequency please?

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774104/android-audio-fft-to-retrieve-specific-frequency-magnitude-using-audiorecord

Comment: Thanks, I did but was hoping for something simpler like a library or framework that would just provide the frequency.