# Analyse AudioTrack on Android (Alternatives to Visualizer)

Tags: android, visualization, audio-recording, audiorecord, audiotrack

I want to analyse the recorded microphone-sound of my Android application.

Unfortunately the [Visualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) is only able to work on an [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) that is currently being played back. Currently I'm recording with [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) and copy the data into an AudioTrack where the visualizer is listening on. But this architecture causes a terrible playback-record-loop.

One workaround was to turn the volume of the AudioTrack down to the lowest possible level while recording, but this doesn't sound like a good solution at all.

Is there any alternative to the [Visualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) class that provides means to capture FFT-data from the recorded track?

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens if you pass the audio session id of the `AudioRecord` object to the `Visualizer`?

`Visualiser mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mAudioRecord.getAudioSessionId());`

Comment: `AudioRecord` unfortunately does not provide a method like `getAudioSessionId()`. 
Another problem with my temporary workaround is, that lowering the volume of the device, will also mute the audioTrack which means that no analysis is going on anymore.

Comment: According to the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#getAudioSessionId()) it does have `getAudioSessionId()` granted it's only available in API level 16 and higher.

Comment: `RuntimeException`: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error -4

Comment: Heh, OK. Well at least we know that doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @Alexander, could you post a full working example somewhere please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android audio FFT to retrieve specific frequency magnitude using audiorecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774104/android-audio-fft-to-retrieve-specific-frequency-magnitude-using-audiorecord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now, by analyzing the data directly from the AudioRecord as described in [Android audio FFT to retrieve specific frequency magnitude using audiorecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774104/android-audio-fft-to-retrieve-specific-frequency-magnitude-using-audiorecord).

Answer (score 0):

additional.
it says

AudioFlinger    createEffect_l() effect Visualizer (flags 00000008) created on wrong thread type 3
AudioEffect set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -22

after searching "created on wrong thread type" it found that there's something wrong with Visualizing input signal. I struggled so far but was fruitless.