# How to remove frequency components from time series?

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, fft

I have the time series below

[image]

I want to check for cycles in order to remove them (as part of the usual pre-processing of time series), so I apply FFT.

```
# Number of samplepoints
N = len(y)
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 # 1 day
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N/2)
components = 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N//2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 5))
ax.plot(xf, components)
```

This results in the following plot.

[image]

I want to remove the four greatest components. In order to do this I'm implementing the formula below.

[image]

```
max_components = sorted(components, reverse=True)[:4]
idx_max_comp = []

for comp in max_components:
    for i in range(len(components)):
        if components[i] == comp:
            idx_max_comp.append(i)
            break

cycle_signal = np.zeros(len(y))
for idx in idxs:
    a, b = (2.0/N) * np.real(yf[idx]), (2.0/N) * np.imag(yf[idx])
    fi = xf[idx]
    cycle_signal += (a * np.cos(2 * np.pi * fi * x)) + (b * np.sin(2 * np.pi * fi * x))

y = y - cycle_signal
```

But when I apply FFT again it's easy to see it didn't work.

[image]

Why?

Comment: Have you tried to use the statsmodel module? Like it is shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672236/time-series-decomposition-function-in-python?

Comment: Check this nice example I've found on another post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968418/python-designing-a-time-series-filter-after-fourier-analysis

Comment: In the FFT array `yf` set the values corresponding to the peaks to zero.  Since these peaks are not single points, you will have to set small ranges of values to zero.  After that, just take the inverse FFT, and you will have your desired result.

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I figured out the same solution. What I'd like to know, is there any mathematical way to figure out the bandwidths to remove, or is it done by eyeballing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the following:

`T = 1.0 # 1 day`

The sampling frequency is defined as the number of samples per second if you have one sample a day your sampling frequency is f = (1/24*60*60) which is approximately 11.57407 uHz (micro-Hertz) and your Nyquist frequency will be at 5.787035 uHz is approximately 2 days. This means that you can't check for occurrences of cycles more frequently than once every two days.

Comment: Can you please describe your answer more briefly?